# Wifi not able to connect to secure networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 22.10

After  fresh system installation all worked well: cable and wifi connection.
After updating system (apt update ...) bluetooth and wifi stopped working. Network is working by wire, but not throught wifi. Bluetooth I fixed by removing all packages related to pulseaudio and installing pipewire ones. Unfortunately WiFi did not started to work =(

I am running on Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel 5.19.0-23-generic.

here is my hardware list, adapter is visible, NetworkManager asks password to connect to WiFi

```
➜  ~ lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: e4:a8:df:b7:84:a8
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-23-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.139 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:52 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1604000-d1604fff memory:d1600000-d1603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 38:d5:7a:be:8c:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.19.0-23-generic firmware=____010000-20220608210922 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:65 memory:fc02000000-fc020fffff memory:fc02100000-fc02103fff memory:fc02104000-fc02104fff
```

Here is NetworkManager logs

```
nov   24 00:31:13 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242673.3338] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9888] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9891] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'asus123' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'ssid' value 'asus123'
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov   24 00:31:21 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242681.9893] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov   24 00:31:22 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242682.0116] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
nov   24 00:31:25 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242685.7267] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov   24 00:31:25 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242685.9374] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:31:35 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242695.9560] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:31:39 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242699.6511] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov   24 00:31:39 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242699.8656] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:31:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242707.7083] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
nov   24 00:31:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242707.7084] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242707.7086] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'asus123'
nov   24 00:31:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242707.7087] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3713] policy: auto-activating connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3716] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3717] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3720] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3721] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'asus123' has security, but secrets are required.
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3721] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3727] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3729] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3730] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'asus123' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'ssid' value 'asus123'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.3731] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.4111] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov   24 00:31:51 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242711.6294] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:01 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242721.6551] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:32:05 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242725.3112] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov   24 00:32:05 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242725.5293] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:15 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242735.5481] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:32:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242736.7086] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
nov   24 00:32:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242736.7086] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242736.7089] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'asus123'
nov   24 00:32:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242736.7090] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1314] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1317] policy: auto-activating connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1319] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1320] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1323] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1325] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'asus123' has security, but secrets are required.
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1325] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1334] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1335] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1337] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'asus123' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1337] Config: added 'ssid' value 'asus123'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1337] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1337] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1337] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1338] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1338] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.1727] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov   24 00:32:19 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242739.3811] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242749.4041] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:32:33 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242753.1228] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov   24 00:32:33 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242753.3373] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:43 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242763.3559] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:32:44 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242764.7089] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
nov   24 00:32:44 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242764.7090] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:44 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242764.7092] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'asus123'
nov   24 00:32:44 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242764.7094] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0231] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0233] policy: auto-activating connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0236] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'asus123' (cf27a321-1d47-4e27-8b94-e29001b6fb15)
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0236] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0238] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0239] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'asus123' has security, but secrets are required.
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0239] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0245] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0246] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0247] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'asus123' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0247] Config: added 'ssid' value 'asus123'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0248] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0248] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0248] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0248] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0248] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.0616] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov   24 00:32:47 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242767.2853] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:32:57 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242777.3071] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:33:00 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242780.9635] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov   24 00:33:01 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242781.1774] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
nov   24 00:33:11 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242791.2004] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov   24 00:33:12 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242792.7092] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
nov   24 00:33:12 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242792.7093] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:33:12 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <warn>  [1669242792.7096] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'asus123'
nov   24 00:33:12 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242792.7098] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 00:33:14 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[1311]: <info>  [1669242794.8677] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

I have tried to connect on my mobile phone hotspot network, it succed

```
nov   24 08:55:15 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272915.7157] device (wlo1): disconnecting for new activation request.
nov   24 08:55:15 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272915.7157] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:15 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272915.7161] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="b1096216-815a-40e1-bf03-ed89af4ed64b" name="tosha" pid=3504 uid=1000 result="succ>
nov   24 08:55:15 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272915.9693] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0126] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0126] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0126] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0850] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'tosha' (b1096216-815a-40e1-bf03-ed89af4ed64b)
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0853] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0857] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0859] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0860] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'tosha' has security, but secrets are required.
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0860] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0865] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0866] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0867] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'tosha' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'ssid' value 'tosha'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.0868] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1251] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1302] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1942] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1942] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "tosha"
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1945] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.1948] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.2171] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed new lease, address=192.168.43.90
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.2242] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.2252] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.2253] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:16 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272916.2256] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
nov   24 08:55:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272929.3837] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov   24 08:55:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272929.4046] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
nov   24 08:55:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272929.4046] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov   24 08:55:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272929.4046] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed no lease
nov   24 08:55:29 kitru-idea3 NetworkManager[60309]: <info>  [1669272929.4889] policy: set 'tosha' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
```

Moreover I have one old router, I configured and tried to connect. Looks like problem not in rounter.

as  I can see, both are using WPA2 auth, while tosha (mobile) works, asus and danon not.

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       C2:BF:24:46:D7:D0  tosha             Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
        04:92:26:64:B9:8C  asus123           Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        A4:2B:B0:CA:A2:14  secret_danon      Infra  7     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
```

more details

```
iwconfig wlo1                                                                     
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"tosha"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: C2:BF:24:46:D7:D0   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, so far it least.

1. install mainline tool (ukuu updated) and installed latest kernel  5.19.17
2. reinstall again networkmanager (apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome )
3. restart

as result network just started to work + bluetooth buttons for volume up/down started to work also.